# Split audio into multiple chuncks javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one audio file and I want to split it into several files, however, I only get one file out of this.
So first I calculate the duration of the adio, then I do a single split and then into multiple split. But I continue to have this error: Nan
Do you know what I did wrong?

```
class Audio {
    constructor(output_folder, input_filepath) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(input_filepath) || !fs.statSync(input_filepath).isFile()) {
            throw new Error('Invalid input file');
        }
        this.input_filepath = input_filepath;
        this.input_filename = this.getInputFilename(input_filepath);
        this.output_folder = output_folder;
        this.audio = ffmpeg(input_filepath);
    }

    get_duration() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.audio.ffprobe((err, metadata) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(metadata.format.duration);
                }
            });
        });
    }

   

    async multiple_split(sec_per_split) {
        const total_duration = this.audio.duration();
        const total_sec = Math.ceil(total_duration * 0.001);
        const num_splits = Math.ceil(total_sec / sec_per_split);
        console.log(`Total duration: ${total_duration}`);
        console.log(`Total seconds: ${total_sec}`);
        console.log(`Seconds per split: ${sec_per_split}`);
        console.log(`Number of splits: ${num_splits}`);
        for (let i = 0; i < num_splits; i++) {
            const start_sec = i * sec_per_split;
            const end_sec = Math.min(start_sec + sec_per_split, total_sec);
            console.log(`Split ${i}: ${start_sec} - ${end_sec}`);
            const split_filename = `${start_sec}_${this.input_filename}`;
            await this.single_split(start_sec * 1000, end_sec * 1000, split_filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I would discourage the overriding of the `Audio` with a custom class since there's already the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio constructor

Comment: On which line do you get your NaN error?

Comment: it's in the logs @OskarGrosser. Since the file doesn't have the duration, the number of splits will be Nan